# QSplashScreen disappears too quickly

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qtimer

I am trying to show a `QSplashScreen` before launching my application. **The problem** I have is that the `QSplashScreen` disappears too quickly. I would like it to show for 2 seconds before the real application loads. 
Below the small example I built to show the error:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/dredgingSplash.png"));
    splash->show();
    Qt::Alignment topRight = Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop;
    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("Setting up the main window..."), topRight, Qt::white);

    QTimer::singleShot(2500, splash, SLOT(close()));
    MainWindow w;
    QTimer::singleShot(2500, &w, SLOT(show()));

    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("loading modules..."), topRight, Qt::white);
    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("Establishing Connections..."), topRight, Qt::white);

    w.show();
    delete splash;
    return a.exec();
}
```

**EDITS** using `QSplashScreen::finish()` from [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#finish):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/dredgingSplash.png"));
    splash->show();
    Qt::Alignment topRight = Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop;
    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("Setting up the main window..."), topRight, Qt::white);

    MainWindow w;

    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("loading modules..."), topRight, Qt::white);
    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("Establishing Connections..."), topRight, Qt::white);

    w.show();    
    splash->finish(&w);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**EDITS 2** using a class:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSplashScreen>
#include <QTimer>

class ShowImageTime {
public:
    void slInit();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/dredgingSplash.png"));
    splash->show();
    Qt::Alignment topRight = Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop;
    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("Setting up the main window..."), topRight, Qt::white);

    MainWindow w;

    QTimer::singleShot(3000, splash, SLOT(close()));// close splash after 4s
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, &w, SLOT(ShowImageTime::slInit(this->show)));// mainwindow reappears after 4s

    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("loading modules..."), topRight, Qt::white);
    splash->showMessage(QObject::tr("Establishing Connections..."), topRight, Qt::white);

    w.show();    
    splash->finish(&w);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I tried to play with the `QTimer` as I thought that could be the potential problem due to priority of loading, but unfortunately if I change `QTimer::singleShot(2500, splash, SLOT(close()));` with `QTimer::singleShot(12500, splash, SLOT(close()));` or even higher numbers, there is literally no difference, so I am not sure why that is not an option.

Also I came across [this source](https://forum.qt.io/topic/49720/solved-qsplashscreen-doesn-t-show-unless-i-run-qapplication-processevents-1000-times) and I also followed [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html) but that also did not help me to figure out the problem.
Also [this post](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1906-Problem-with-Splash-Screen) suggests that the problem keeps being related to the `QTimer` but I don't see how since bigger or smaller intervals seems not to count.

What am I missing to keep the `QSplashScreen` to stay for 2 seconds instead of disappearing (or not even see it) right away?
Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: Did you try to use `QSplashScreen::finish()` function instead of timers?

Comment: Hello vahancho, no I didn't but I give it a try one second

Comment: It is not giving any difference. From [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html#finish), what should I modify on the sample code ? Is `QTimer` still needed or not anymore?

Comment: You don't need timers at all, IMO. Please look at the same page you referred to see the usage example. You should call `splash->finish(&w);` after `w.show()` call and remove all timers.

Comment: Ok I see. Yes it works now without `QTimers` but the image still disappears super quickly. How could I make it stay for 2 seconds though?

Comment: I added the edited version on the question

Comment: I tried **EDIT 2** too using an external class and `QTimer` another time as additional thing but that also gave the same result, the `QSplashScreen` disappeared super quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your code is starting the timer and then continues running. So the MainWindow is created, shown and the SplashScreen is deleted/finished. The timer's timout function will trigger after all this happened. That is why it closes so quickly.

SplashScreens are usually shown, if the application start is very slow, because there is so much going on in the background. In your case, there is basically no load and the code executes super quick.

You could either use a sleep call for 2sec right after calling `splash->show()` or put all the code for closing the SplashScreen, showing the Mainwindow in a timer's timout slot and delete the SplashScreen there.